# How to solve android studio loading project? Cannot load project: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @NotNull method

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to reopen the project in Android studio but it shows the message:

> "Cannot load project: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @NotNull method com/intellij/openapi/progress/ProgressManager.getInstance must not return null".

[image]

How to solve this problem? I already tried restarting Android Studio.But the issue still persists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I solved this by following ways

1.Force stop Android studio from Task Manager

2.Clean all cache

3.Restart laptop

Comment: Can you please explain the reason behind the issue as part of you answer?

Comment: I just restarted my computer and then, it works again.

Answer (score 14):

Closing IDEA via Task Manager and restart it solved it for me. No Laptop restart or cache deleting needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try to restart Android Studio by invalating Cache. Good luck

Go to File
->Invalidate Caches/ Restart

Comment: I tried but can't solved. My Android studio freeze after getting this message :(

Answer (score 2):

If it does not work maybe you can re-install Android Studio.

Comment: I don't want to re-install Android Studio

Comment: @AjayShrestha If you have no other choice?

Comment: I am trying to find the best solution

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before. I solved it by restarting my laptop. And voila, it worked.

Comment: I did but the problem still persist :(

Comment: For me "Invalidate caches\Restart" didn't help!
Only restarting my laptop helped (Windows asked to wait while updating the system).

Answer (score 0):

Running sudo pycharm-educational worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04. I think you can run pycharm as an administrator in windows as well to fix the problem. It can be used for the android studio as well.